# When does Fedora provide extended support releases for Java?

Tags: fedora, java, rolling-release, openjdk

I'm trying to run a jar file which checks the installed version of Java explicitly:

> *** The version you have requested to build requires Java versions between [Java 8, Java 12], but you are using Java 13

I am able to install OpenJDK 11 from my package manager but then only OpenJDK 13 is available as part of the latest rolling release.

In this case, I am required to use the older JDK 11 for this software on Fedora.

I can't find any information abut Fedora's rolling releases for Java. When does the Fedora project decide to provide extended support of a rolling releases?

Comment: What do you mean by “rolling release”?  Are you talking about Fedora or Java?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the availability of Java packages in Fedora [is as follows](https://jvanek.fedorapeople.org/devconf/2018/changesInjavaReleaseProcess.pdf):

- long-term support releases of OpenJDK are available as long as they haven’t reached the end of their life;
- the latest short-term support release is available as the rolling release package.

Thus Fedora 31 currently has OpenJDK 8 ([which is still the default](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Java)), OpenJDK 11, and OpenJDK 13. [Some packages are switching to build with OpenJDK 11](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/archives/list/java-devel@lists.fedoraproject.org/thread/NV5C7DO45T27ZYOLY3HBMVTYNAHKPKY2/), but as far as I’m aware there are no plans currently to switch to OpenJDK 11 as the default.